# Testing solutions for Bert Bos puzzle

Tags: prolog

Working on the [Bert Bos Puzzle](http://mathcs.pugetsound.edu/~tmullen/pages/bertspel/), where I need to print all possible permutations of a sequence (clicks or no clicks) that will turn the whole square red. This will be done by clicking the top row in a sequence of clicks and no clicks. Then, you go to the subsequent row and click squares there to make the first row all red. You progress through the puzzle like this until you  turn the whole square red.

So a possible solution to a 4x4 square would be [click, click, no click, no click] on the first row. You dont have to follow the pattern for any of the lines below, just keep flipping until all blocks on the next line are red and continue till all squares are red.

Im trying to write a predicate that tests all possible permutations of ‘click’ and ‘no click’ for the first row of a square of size N. Right now Im trying to go about it by keeping track of the color of the top row after it has been clicked, then using that to say which squares of the second row should be clicked to make the top row all red.

The problem is I cant figure out how to keep track of the colors of the second row that are changed by clicks from the first row, and then how to keep track of clicks from the second row on and how they affect the rest of the rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far

```
state(no_click).
state(click).

flip(blue, red).
flip(red, blue).

board_permutations(0,[]):- !.
board_permutations(N, [H|T]) :-
  state(H),
  N1 is N - 1,
  board_permutations(N1, T).

first_row_solutions([], []).
first_row_solutions([H1, H2|T], [FirstRow|SecondRow]):-
  H1 = click,
  flip(H1,C),
  flip(H2,C),
  first_row_solutions(H2, FirstRow).
first_row_solutions([H|T], [FRH1, FRH2, FRH3|FRT], [SR1, SR2, SR3|SRT]) :-
  H = click,
  flip(FRH1, C1),
  flip(FRH2, C2),
  flip(FRH3, C3),
  %flip(SR1, S1),   I was thinking I could keep track of the second row colors here
  %flip(SR2, S2),
  %flip(SR3, S3)
  %FlipListRow1 = [C1, C2, C3 | T],
  %FlipListRow2 = [S1, S2, S3|T],
  first_row_solutions(H, FRH3).


%Possible predicate to handle row 2, 3, 4 etc --> ClickList is what clicks to do on row 3 to make row 2 red, etc
%row_n_solutions(FlipListRow2, ClickList)


generate_board(0, [], _).
generate_board(N, [H|T], ConstantN) :-
  generate_row(ConstantN, H),
  N =< 12, N >= 1,
  N2 is N-1,
  generate_board(N2, T, ConstantN).

generate_row(0, []) :- !.
generate_row(N, [H | T]) :-
  N =< 12, N >= 1,
  N2 is N-1,
  H = blue,
  generate_row(N2, T).

test(X) :- generate_board(5,X,5).
test1(X) :- solutions([no_click, click, no_click, no_click], X).
```

Comment: I think that a list of lists isn't the easier data representation for this puzzle (BTW, author'name it's B**e**rt Bos). You have no choices apart carrying the whole matrix around and change 3 (or 2) rows at every attempt (a click)

Answer (score 1):

@CapelliC has already suggested one possible approach: You can **carry along** the matrix (using predicate arguments), and use this to always inspect the current state of any surrounding cells.

Complementing this approach, I would also like to point out a different method to approach the whole task: We can consider this puzzle as finding a suitable **linear combination** of *vectors* from the finite field GF(2). The number of clicks can be represented as an **integer** coefficient for each vector.

It only remains to establish a *correspondence* between board positions and vector indices. We can define such a relation as follows:

```
n_id_x_y(N, ID, X, Y) :-
        ID #= Y*N + X,
        N1 #= N - 1,
        [X,Y] ins 0..N1.
```

Example:

```
?- n_id_x_y(4, 6, X, Y).
X = 2,
Y = 1.
```

Note that I specified `4` to obtain a mapping that works for 4×4 boards.

This uses **CLP(FD) constraints** and works in all directions, including for example:

```
?- n_id_x_y(4, ID, 3, 2).
ID = 11.
```

Based on this, we can also relate any index to its neighbours, again denoted by their unique indices:

```
n_id_neighbour(N, ID, NID) :-
        n_id_x_y(N, ID, X, Y),
        (   (   NX #= X - 1, NY #= Y
            ;   NX #= X + 1, NY #= Y
            )
        ;   (   NX #= X, NY #= Y - 1
            ;   NX #= X, NY #= Y + 1
            )
        ),
        n_id_x_y(N, NID, NX, NY).
```

Clicking on any board position *flips* the colour of that position and its defined neighbours. We will use a **Boolean** vector and let `1` denote that the colour of the position that corresponds to this index is affected:

```
n_id_vector(N, ID, Vs) :-
        V #= N*N,
        V1 #= V - 1,
        ID in 0..V1,
        indomain(ID),
        findall(NID, n_id_neighbour(N, ID, NID), Ns),
        sort([ID|Ns], IDs),
        length(Vs, V),
        phrase(ids_vector(IDs, 0), Vs, Zeroes),
        maplist(=(0), Zeroes).

ids_vector([], _) --> [].
ids_vector([ID|IDs], Pos0) -->
        { Gap #= ID - Pos0,
          Pos #= ID + 1,
          length(Zeroes, Gap),
          maplist(=(0), Zeroes) },
        Zeroes,
        [1],
        ids_vector(IDs, Pos).
```

For example, clicking on entry `0-0` affects precisely three other cells, which are indicated by `1`:

```
?- n_id_vector(4, 0, Vs).
Vs = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0|...].
```

We are now ready to describe what we expect from a solution: A solution consists of a list of **coefficients**, one for each vector, such that the sum of the scalar products (vector times coefficient for each vector) *modulo 2* is equal to `(1,1,...,1)`. This means that the colour of *each* cell has changed.

```
n_solution(N, Cs) :-
        findall(Vs, n_id_vector(N,_,Vs), Vss),
        same_length(Vss, Cs),
        Cs ins 0..1,
        maplist(flip_cell(Cs), Vss),
        label(Cs).

flip_cell(Cs, Ts) :-
        scalar_product(Ts, Cs, #=, Sum),
        Sum mod 2 #= 1.
```

Note that in this case, due to the inherent symmetry, there is no need to transpose the matrix.

The fact that we are reasoning over *Boolean* algebra already entails that the order in which the cells are clicked does not affect the outcome, and also that each of the vectors needs to be used at most once in any solution.

Here are solutions for a 4×4 board:

```
?- n_solution(4, Cs).
Cs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
Cs = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] ;
Cs = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ;
Cs = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] ;
etc.
```

Each solution indicates precisely which of the cells we must click. For example, the first solution:

[image: 4x4 first solution]

Here is one of the longest solutions for this board size:

[image]

And this is one of the shortest:

[image]

You can of course also apply this approach to other board sizes, such as 7×7:

[image]

Or 12×12:

[image]